# Radius of convergence of a series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

This came up in an old question paper I was going through. I am looking for the radius of convergence of the series whose partial sums are:

$$ S_n = \sum \frac{(a+nx)^n}{n!} $$

My initial attempt was to try and find the extrema for the function $f_n(x) = S_n$, here that would be $x = \frac{-a}{n}$ Should I proceed with this?? I also see that $S> e^a.e^x$; but not sure whether that will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use [Ratio Test](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RatioTest.html)

let the $r$th term $\displaystyle T_r=\frac{(a+rx)^r}{r!}$

$$\implies\frac{T_{r+1}}{T_r}=\left(\frac{a+(r+1)x}{a+rx}\right)^r\cdot\left(\frac{a+(r+1)x}r\right)$$
$$=\left(\left(1+\frac x{a+rx}\right)^{\frac{a+rx}x}\right)^{\frac {rx}{a+rx}}\cdot\left(\frac{a+x}r+x\right)$$

$$\lim_{r\to\infty}\frac{T_{r+1}}{T_r}=e\cdot x$$  as $\displaystyle \lim_{r\to\infty}\frac {rx}{a+rx}=1$

Comment: @Vishesh, But the test will fail if $\displaystyle e\cdot x=1\iff x=\frac1e$. In that case, we can try Raabe’s Test and Logarithmic Test (http://mathumatiks.com/subpage-401-Raabe%E2%80%99s-Test-and-Logarithmic-Test.htm)

Answer (score 3):

From Stirling $\;n!\sim \left(\dfrac ne\right)^n\sqrt{2\pi n}\;$ as $\,n\to \infty\,$  so that :
\begin{align} 
\frac{(a+nx)^n}{n!}&\sim \frac{(nx)^n}{\sqrt{2\pi n}} \left(\dfrac en\right)^n\\
&\sim \frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi n}} \left(e\,x\right)^n\\
\end{align}
I'll let you conclude (comparing $x$ and $1/e$).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, however I was looking for something that preferably doesnt involve Stirling's approximation.Apologies

Comment: No problem @Visheh.

Comment: @RaymondManzoni, How to handle $x=\frac1e$ in this method?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: well the equivalence gives $\frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi n}}$ and implies divergence.

Comment: @RaymondManzoni, you mean  $\frac1{\sqrt{2n\pi}}$ which is equivalent to a $p$ series with $p=\frac12<1,$ right? Thanks for your clarification

Comment: This does work more efficiently, I think MSE should allow for more than one accepted answer :)